# Case when value of a group is 1 then all values of that group should be replaced by 1 - SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm writing a query (using Athena - AWS) and I need to substitute all values from a group if there's at least one occurrence of another value. To exemplify:

My original dataframe

```
ID   v1 v2 v3
123  0  0  1
123  0  1  0
123  1  1  0
456  1  0  0 
456  0  0  0
```

What I need: case when v1, v2 or v3 assume value 1 group by ID, then the whole column that contains 1 group by ID should be 1.

This is the output I need:

```
ID   v1 v2 v3
123  1  1  1
456  1  0  0
```

Since v1, v2, v3 had at least one number 1 in the group ID 123, then all these columns for this group should be 1. However, ID 456 had at least one number 1 only in column v1, then v1 will be 1 and v2, v3 will remain 0.

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: Your original dataframe does not have a value of `1` in the column `v3` as mentioned in your question. Was this a typo?

Comment: sorry, just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following

```sql
SELECT
   ID,
   MAX(v1) as v1,
   MAX(v2) as v2,
   MAX(v3) as v3
FROM
   your_table
GROUP BY
   ID
```

Comment: if v1,v2,v3 are string type, should I first replace for 1 or 0 and then do what you did? or there's a simpler way?

Comment: @rebar, MAX() works on character columns too.

Comment: @rebar `MAX` will also work on string types and would return the expected results for `1` and `0` for string.  See experiment in [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4SaBF9L4M1kwKcSC27C4ZR/0)